# Read files in Python from OneDrive

Tags: python, onedrive

I need to read all files in a folder on OneDrive, I don't know the name of the files and I want to avoid using the download URL.
Is there a way to download all the files directly? Is there a way to read the files in python without knowing the filename and download URL?

Comment: see https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read all the files of OneDrive and copy it with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887052/how-to-read-all-the-files-of-onedrive-and-copy-it-with-python)